# What's the meaning of $f'$ in the context of congruence equations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, derivatives, notation

Here is page 125 of the 6th edition of Hardy and Wright's "An introduction to the theory of numbers".  (That's chapter VIII, section 8.3, congruences to a prime-power modulus.)

[image]

**Question**.  What is that $f'$?  (In this context, they usually use $\xi$ to represent a root.)

It looks like the derivative of $f$.  But, in that case, I'm lacking the understanding required to follow their conclusion regarding the number of roots.  I haven't read the entire book, but I can't seem to find where the prerequisite for this is or even a definition of this prime-notation.  Can you offer some pointers here?

Comment: It would indeed be the derivative, probably a formal derivative?

Comment: I agree that it's a "formal derivative" (see, eg, [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative)). Even in contexts where a limit-based definition of a function derivative doesn't make any sense, the operation $x^n \to n x^{n-1}$ can still be surprisingly useful.

Comment: This is a situation where Theorem 123 case (c) from page 124 applies, and indeed $f'$ denotes the derivative of the integral polynomial $f$. You might want to read at least a few more pages of the book …